# How to all deselect all the chosen options with jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-selectors

I use this [link](https://www.cssscript.com/demo/filterable-checkable-multi-select/) (Select 2 with multiselct option) for my HTML pages.
How can I deselect all selected option by J Query?
I try this code `$('#myIdSelectForm > option').removeAttr("selected");` and so many other J Query codes but not working.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#field2').select2();
});
$('#myIdSelectForm > option').removeAttr("selected");
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" integrity="sha512-nMNlpuaDPrqlEls3IX/Q56H36qvBASwb3ipuo3MxeWbsQB1881ox0cRv7UPTgBlriqoynt35KjEwgGUeUXIPnw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js" integrity="sha512-2ImtlRlf2VVmiGZsjm9bEyhjGW4dU7B6TNwh/hx/iSByxNENtj3WVE6o/9Lj4TJeVXPi4bnOIMXFIJJAeufa0A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<select name="myIdSelectForm" id="field2" multiple="" multiselect-search="true" multiselect-select-all="true" multiselect-max-items="3" style="display: none;">
  <option>Abarth</option>
  <option>Alfa Romeo</option>
  <option>Aston Martin</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
  <option>Bentley</option>
  <option>BMW</option>
  <option>Bugatti</option>
  <option>Cadillac</option>
  <option>Chevrolet</option>
  <option>Chrysler</option>
  <option>Citroën</option>
  <option>Dacia</option>
  <option>Daewoo</option>
  <option>Suzuki</option>
  <option>Tesla</option>
  <option>Toyota</option>
  <option>Volkswagen</option>
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: I see no checkboxes here, only as `<select` element - perhaps you meant to say "deselect all the chosen options"?

Comment: yes my mean is `deselect all the chosen options"` I edit my question tittle, thanks

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a proper id selector `#field2` not a name as an id.
Here I use a second button just to illustrate clearing all when we click that button by triggering a custom event and then clearing the value then triggering a change.

I also added a button to clear just one - the last selected option in this case.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#field2').select2();
  $('#field2').on('clear-all', function(event) {
    console.log('Doing:', event.type);
    $(this).val(null).trigger('change');
  }).on('clear-last', function(event) {
    console.log('Doing:', event.type);
    $(this).find('option:selected')
      .last().prop("selected", false);
    $(this).trigger("change");
  });

  $("#test-deselect").on("click", function() {
    console.log('clearing');
    $('#field2').trigger('clear-all');
  });
  $("#test-deselect-last-one").on("click", function() {
    console.log('clearing last');
    $('#field2').trigger('clear-last');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" integrity="sha512-nMNlpuaDPrqlEls3IX/Q56H36qvBASwb3ipuo3MxeWbsQB1881ox0cRv7UPTgBlriqoynt35KjEwgGUeUXIPnw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js" integrity="sha512-2ImtlRlf2VVmiGZsjm9bEyhjGW4dU7B6TNwh/hx/iSByxNENtj3WVE6o/9Lj4TJeVXPi4bnOIMXFIJJAeufa0A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<select name="myIdSelectForm" id="field2" multiple="" multiselect-search="true" multiselect-select-all="true" multiselect-max-items="3">
  <option selected>Abarth</option>
  <option>Alfa Romeo</option>
  <option selected>Aston Martin</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
  <option>Bentley</option>
  <option>BMW</option>
  <option>Bugatti</option>
  <option>Cadillac</option>
  <option>Chevrolet</option>
  <option>Chrysler</option>
  <option>Citroën</option>
  <option>Dacia</option>
  <option>Daewoo</option>
  <option>Suzuki</option>
  <option>Tesla</option>
  <option>Toyota</option>
  <option>Volkswagen</option>
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option></option>
</select>

<button id="test-deselect" type="button">Deselect all</button>

<button id="test-deselect-last-one" type="button">Deselect last one</button>
```

Comment: `select2.min.css` and `select2.min.js` have Overlap with other css and forms.

Comment: @hiIama  This is just a test for an answer here.  How you create and include those from the select2 source of these is up to you and how you manage your project and build your application.  I included them here only to illustrate for this answer as a runnable snippet